# Export issues with the MUI-X Data-grid (pagination, image format, optimization)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, datagridview

**Description:**

Problems:

1. Excel Export with server Pagination:

   - Difficulty exporting all data-grid pages to Excel at once. Export only downloads currently visible rows.
   - Is there a built-in or recommended way to export all data across all pages?
2. Column Format for Non-Native Data Types (e.g., Images):

   - The GridColDef options did not allow me to export an actual image element (only native types were supported).
     Does MUI-X support cell formatting in such a way that images are included in the exported Excel file?
3. Resource Optimization:

   - There are concerns about the efficiency of RAM and browser resources when exporting large Excel files with many rows, taking into account multipage tables.
   - Are there any optimization strategies or best practices for managing RAM and browser performance during large Excel exports?

**Current behavior:**

- Problem 1. Only the current page's rows are exported.
- Problem 2. Images in cells are not exported to Excel.
- Problem 3. Not yet tested, but concerned about potential inefficiency in resource usage in large data-sets.

**Context:**

As part of our evaluation of X-data-grid-premium, I need to generate an Excel report that can contain images, a number of pages that are fetched from the backend, as well as some extra information on each row.

**Steps to reproduce**

1. Excel Export with server Pagination:

   - Difficulty exporting all data-grid pages to Excel at once. Export only downloads currently visible rows.
   - Is there a built-in or recommended way to export all data across all pages?
2. Column Format for Non-Native Data Types (e.g., Images):

   - The GridColDef options did not allow me to export an actual image element (only native types were supported).
   - Does MUI-X support cell formatting in such a way that images are included in the exported Excel file?
3. Resource Optimization:

   - There are concerns about the efficiency of RAM and browser resources when exporting large Excel files with many rows, taking into account multipage tables.
   - Are there any optimization strategies or best practices for managing RAM and browser performance during large Excel exports?

**Problem 1.** Excel export should include all rows across all pages.

**Problem 2.** Cells formatted with images should show up in the Excel export.

**Problem 3.** The export process should be optimized to use RAM and browser resources efficiently, particularly for large datasets, for example, chunked page export.